# react native navigationOptions navigate to other route from header button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate to a different route when a button in the header is clicked.
Using react-navigation in my react-native project.

```
static navigationOptions   = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    title: 'Header Text',
    headerRight: 
        <Button 
            title="Settings"
            backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
            color="rgba(0,122,255,1)"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('settings')}
        />,
});
```

> ERROR - Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not
>   valid as a React child (found: object with keys {style}

My package.json entry for react-navigation

```
"react-navigation": "^1.5.10"
```

None of the solutions described here seems to work. Probably due to different version??

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/286

Comment: Seems to work fine in even in your described `package`, do you get this error after `button click`? If so please post the code for the `settings screen`.

Comment: it was actually an issue with my settings screen. nothing wrong with this code. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { navigate } = navigation
  return  {
    title: 'Header Text',
    headerRight:(
      <Button 
        title="Settings" backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)" color="rgba(0,122,255,1)"
        onPress={() =>navigate('settings')}
      />
    )
  }             
}
```